# Como criar um objeto solicitando dados ao usuário e executando a partir de uma função?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Eu criei uma classe simples, eu consigo criar um objeto, porém estou desenvolvendo um CRUD que preciso criar o objeto a partir de uma função. Veja o meu exemplo:

```
class Funcionario:
    def __init__(self, nome, cargo, salario):
        self.nome = nome
        self.cargo = cargo
        self.salario = salario


def registrar():
    func = Funcionario(
        nome = input('Nome: '),
        cargo = input('Cargo: '),
        salario=(input('Salário: '))
    )

def modificar():
    func ?
```

O problema é que a criação do objeto fica dentro da função, ou seja, não é global.

Se eu tento criar um método alterar na classe e vou executar a partir de uma função editar o cargo, por exemplo, como faço para instanciar o objeto, sendo que ele está na outra função? E se eu deixar de fora, ele fica chamando toda hora a criação do objeto, o que não quero.

---

Código completo:

```
class Funcionario:
    def __init__(self, nome, cargo, salario):
        self.nome = nome
        self.cargo = cargo
        self.salario = salario
    
    def altera_cargo(self):
        novo_cargo = input('Novo cargo: ')
        self.cargo = novo_cargo
        print('Cargo atualizado para {}'.format(self.cargo))
    
    def altera_salario(self):
        novo_salario = float(input('Novo salário: '))
        self.salario = novo_salario
        print('Salário atualizado para R$ {}'.format(self.salario))


def registra():
    return Funcionario(
        nome = input('Nome: '),
        cargo = input('Cargo: '),
        salario = float(input('Salário: '))
    )


def menu():
    opcao = int(input('1. Novo\n2. Editar cargo\n3. Editar salário\n--> '))

    if opcao == 1:
        registra()
        print('\n')
        menu()
    if opcao == 2:
        altera_cargo() # como acessar o objeto ?
        print('\n')
        menu()
    if opcao == 3:
        altera_salario() # como acessar o objeto ?
        print('\n')
        menu()
    else:
        exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    menu()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta fazer a função retornar o funcionário que foi criado. Depois você passa esse funcionário para a função que modifica, e lá dentro você muda os dados que precisar. Ex:

```
def registrar(): # retorna um novo funcionario
    return Funcionario(
        nome = input('Nome: '),
        cargo = input('Cargo: '),
        salario = float(input('Salário: '))
    )

def modificar(func): # modifica os dados de um funcionário
    func.salario = float(input('Novo salário:'))
    func.cargo = input('Novo cargo:')
    # etc...

# registra um funcionário e modifica
funcionario = registrar()
modificar(funcionario)

# registra outro funcionário e modifica
outro_funcionario = registrar()
modificar(outro_funcionario)

etc...
```

O `return` faz com que o valor seja retornado para quem chamou a função. Assim, cada chamada de `registrar` retorna uma nova instância de `Funcionario`, que você pode manipular separadamente.

E a função `modificar` recebe um funcionário como parâmetro, e lá dentro ela modifica os dados deste.

Obs: usei [`float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) para converter o salário para um número, pois me parece que não faz sentido o salário ser uma string (só lembrando que vai dar erro se não for digitado um número).

---

Agora, se a ideia é chamar métodos do próprio funcionário, então primeiro você precisa criá-lo.

E se quer ficar repetindo o menu várias vezes, não chame a função dentro dela mesma. Em vez disso, faça um *loop* infinito e interrompa-o usando `break`:

```
def menu():
    func = None
    while True:
        opcao = int(input('1. Novo\n2. Editar cargo\n3. Editar salário\n--> '))
        if opcao == 1:
            func = registra()
        elif opcao == 2:
            if func is None:
                print('funcionário ainda não foi criado')
            else:
                func.altera_cargo()
        elif opcao == 3:
            if func is None:
                print('funcionário ainda não foi criado')
            else:
                func.altera_salario()
        else:
            break # sai do loop
        print('\n')
```

Ou seja, eu tenho um funcionário `func` que no início não tem nenhum valor (`None`). Ao registrar, a função `registra()` retorna este funcionário, e uma vez tendo ele, eu posso chamar os métodos do mesmo (`altera_cargo` e `altera_salario`).

Repare no `while True`, ele fica repetindo tudo até encontrar um `break` (a diferença é que `exit` sai do programa, já `break` interrompe apenas o `while`, então se tivesse algum código depois dele, este seria executado).

Isso é melhor do que o que você fez, pois ficar chamando a função `menu` dentro dela mesma (que é chamado de [recursão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/438762/112052)) pode causar um estouro de pilha. Prefira usar um *loop*, que não tem esse problema.

Comment: respondi seu comentário com uma pergunta, desculpe. Consegue dar uma olhada no painel da pergunta?

Comment: @Tguitarful Na verdade você usou o campo de respostas, que é destinado apenas para soluções. O certo é você editar a pergunta e colocar o código lá (já fiz isso, mas das próximas vezes, edite a própria pergunta) - também atualizei minha resposta

Comment: Opa, da maneira que você mostrou funcionou mesmo, obrigado! Desculpe ser insistente, é que o código está ficando cada vez mais complexo. A ideia principal é separar isso. Então por exemplo, como o func ficou amarrado a função menu, ficou inacessível fora dali. A pretensão agora é criar uma função para cada tarefa, criar, modificar, excluir e consultar. O objeto que é criado precisa ser acessível a todas essas funções, já que o menu agora estará em um arquivo separado e chamará essas funções quando necessário. Assim como gravação no banco de dados também.

Comment: @Tguitarful Por favor entenda que o formato do [pt.so] é de perguntas/respostas. Vc faz uma pergunta específica e as pessoas respondem somente aquilo, nada mais. [Não é como em um fórum](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/112052), em que a discussão pode se alongar e o problema pode ir mudando. Então se vc tem outra dúvida (mesmo que esteja relacionada com esta), o melhor é [fazer outra pergunta](/questions/ask). Mas de forma geral, bastaria fazer a função `menu` retornar o funcionário. Aí quem chamar o `menu` pega o retorno (`func1 = menu()`, depois `func2 = menu()`, etc)...

Comment: ...e você usa esses funcionários da maneira que quiser. Claro que tem inúmeras formas de fazer, e por isso talvez seja melhor outra pergunta mesmo, pois aí as respostas podem ser mais focadas. Mas enfim, se a resposta resolveu o seu problema (o que está na pergunta, não o outro que vc só mencionou agora), vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. Quanto ao outro problema, sugiro que faça outra pergunta...

Comment: ...que é melhor, não só para manter o site mais organizado - uma pergunta por problema específico - mas também porque novas perguntas ficam visíveis na página principal, aí todos podem ver e vc tem mais chances de ter uma resposta. Colocando nos comentários, menos gente vai ver.

Comment: Sim, ainda estou me acostumando com o formato do site. De toda forma vlw pela ajuda. No post original, sua resposta resolveu o problema! Obrigado pela força!